# Angular 5 bind date to field (reactive forms)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've got a problem with input type date. I want to bind data from component. Here's my field:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="dateOfReport">Data zgłoszenia błędu:</label>
    <input type="date" formControlName="dateOfReport" id="dateOfReport" class="form-control" [value]="report.dateOfReport | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'"> {{report.dateOfReport | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
  </div>
```

Here's how variable dateOfReport look:

```
new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10)
```

Where I fail? {{ .. }} shows good date, but my field doesn't take it as default.

Comment: I too am having trouble inititating a value on the input[type=date] with reactive forms

Answer (score 0):

When using Reactive Forms, you should not bind data directly to the control, instead use setValue() or patchValue() of FormGroup.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to bind the date to the input when creating a form using reactive forms.

I'm using Angular 11.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dateOfReport">Report Date</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dateOfReport" id="dateOfReport" formControlName="dateOfReport" />
</div>
```

And here is my angular component

```
// ...other imports
import { formatDate } from "@angular/common";

// ...

//... creating the form
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  dateOfReport: [formatDate(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd", "en"), [Validators.required]],
  // other form fields
});
```